# How can I enable WPA2 wireless encryption?

Tags: wireless-networking, security, encryption

I suspect someone is hacking into my wifi connection. I changed my password immediately. I don't know how these people are doing it. I was searching ways to secure my connection. Now, I need to know what is WPA2 wireless encryption. I read in this article http://nci.ca/5-tips-protecting-wifi-network-hackers/ about enabling WPA2 wireless encryption for protecting from hacking. I didn't get that part. Can anyone help me how to enable this encryption? My router is Linksys ae6500. 
Also, share your suggestions on wifi security.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. Access the router’s web-based setup page by opening a web browser.  On the Address bar, enter your router’s local IP address then press Enter.  When the login prompt appears, enter your router’s User name and Password (and then change them if default).

NOTE:  The default local IP address of Linksys routers is 192.168.1.1. If you changed it, use the one you've set.

2. You will now be redirected to the main screen of the setup page.  On the setup page, click the **Wireless tab** then click the **Wireless Security sub-tab**.
3. On the **Configuration View** section, click the Manual radio button.
   Other router models, especially the older versions do not have the Manual option and may require you to scroll down the page until you reach the **Wireless Security** section instead.
4. You can now select from the options there.

Your router should support the most commonly used wireless security modes which you can choose from:  WEP, WPA Personal, **WPA2 Personal**, and WPA2/WPA Mixed Mode. Just select WPA2 Personal there instead of WPA or WPA Mixed.

Set new passwords for your wireless part and you're done.

As reminder, make sure you have a password on the web interface of your router too, don't let the default blank/admin one.